# Debian BCM43xx Wireless Device Issues

Tags: debian, wifi

I recently got help here so I decided to ask another question.

I'm facing issues with Broadcom wireless card on my laptop. I'm using [this](http://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx) Wiki page as manual and I'm doing everything EXACTLY as this page states.

b43-fwcutter has been installd successfully, firmware fetched and extracted without any problems. Also `modprobe b43` comes with no problem. However, when I type `iwconfig` I got only two entries:

```
maya@dev:~$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Where is my Ethernet connection. Os course I tried to delete firmware and fetching/extracting it once again by running `dpkg-reconfigure -plow b43-fwcutter` without any luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt above link try this out..

Comment: Why just not using native solution for that? I'm having problems with b43 not with Broadcom Linux hybrid wireless driver.

Comment: if that is not working then you have choice ..

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to check the kernel messages for some error messages.  I remember getting stuck a while back and seeing a very informative error message (complete with link to website) dumped there in the logs.

`dmesg | tail -f`

Or, pipe that to `grep` and look for b43 or [B|b]roadcom to see if it mentions something.  I had similar issues a while back, so I am sorry I cannot be of more help to you.

EDIT: Stupid me.  I am sure you have done this already, but have you done `sudo ifconfig all` and confirmed there is not an installed, but inactive adapter. If so you, you might need to turn it on, something like this `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`, but I am sure we will be unlucky and the wireless adapter has a different name assigned by kernel/udev/what have you.